# Excel Formula Converted to C# returned NaN

Tags: c#, excel, formula

I have formula in excel sheet with returns $205.03. I converted the formula into C# code and it produced NaN. [C# Example on dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/k3uHqP)
Excel formula to calculate the result

Excel formula:`=IFERROR((principalX3/(((1+(1+interestX3*1/12)^(12)-1)^(1/12))^(0) * ((1+(1+interestX3*1/12)^(12)-1)^(1/12))^(0))-0/((1+(1+interestX3*1/12)^(12)-1)^(1/12)-(1+(1+0*1/12)^(12)-1)^(1/12))*((1-((1+(1+interestX3*1/12)^(12)-1)^(1/12))^(-repaymentsX5)*((1+(1+0*1/12)^(12)-1)^(1/12))^(repaymentsX5))/((1+(1+interestX3*1/12)^(12)-1)^(1/12)-(1+(1+0*1/12)^(12)-1)^(1/12))-repaymentsX5*((1+(1+interestX3*1/12)^(12)-1)^(1/12))^(-repaymentsX5)))/(1*(1-0)*(1-0)*(1-((1+(1+interestX3*1/12)^(12)-1)^(1/12))^(-repaymentsX5)*((1+(1+0*1/12)^(12)-1)^(1/12))^(repaymentsX5))/((1+(1+interestX3*1/12)^(12)-1)^(1/12)-(1+(1+0*1/12)^(12)-1)^(1/12))),"")`

Comment: Possible cause of this is the formula syntax you are using or the sequence of the formula.

Comment: thanks, I have made some efforts by making it into parts and its working but not accurate. can you check it please https://dotnetfiddle.net/GpWFbv
for the given inputs the output should be $205.03

Comment: Actually using formula stored on variables is much way easier to read than using actual formula. I think your code is far better than your previous.

Comment: The formula is unnecessary complex. The term `(1+(1+0*1/12)^(12)-1)` for example will always be `1`. Do some math first to simplify the formula.

Comment: In my opinion the whole `Excel` formula can be simplified to `=principalX3/(ABS(1-(1+interestX3*1/12)^(-repaymentsX5))/ABS((interestX3*1/12)))`

Comment: @AxelRichter I tried the simplified formula in Excel, which gives 12054.1 :(

Comment: No, if `principalX3` = 1000, `interestX3` = 0.1 and `repaymentsX5` = 5, then my formula returns 205.0276619.

Comment: Agreed with Axel Richter.  The formula should be simplified due to redundancy.  For example, you have p*1/12 which can be p/12, and the xxxx^0 will be always 1 etc.  And here is an even shorter version: `=principalX3*ABS(interestX3/12)/(ABS(1-(1+interestX3/12)^(-repaymentsX5)))`